# MongoDB: Register codecs (Java)

Tags: java, mongodb, codec

I've been trying for about an hour now to register a codec I made for one of my classes in a game I am working on. The class is called `Item`. I tried the code and suggestions from these 3 places:

- https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/codecs/
- https://matteosilvestri.blogspot.ca/2015/03/overview-of-pluggable-codecs-in-mongodb.html
- https://gist.github.com/JaiHirsch/cada9eaac3e24ef5a62a

and here is the code I cam up with:

```
CodecRegistry defaultCodecRegistry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
MyCodecProvider myCodecProvider = new MyCodecProvider();
ItemCodec itemCodec = new ItemCodec(defaultCodecRegistry);

CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(itemCodec), CodecRegistries.fromProviders(myCodecProvider), defaultCodecRegistry);;
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(codecRegistry).build();

client = new MongoClient("localhost:27017", options);
```

So I built a Codec and codec provider called `MyCodecProvider`, so what am I doing wrong, how can this be so complicated? Am I missing something? It seems more complicated than it needs to be. If you need more code please ask. Thanks.

Edit: The exact error I get is `org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class [Lnet.hollowbit.archipeloserver.items.Item;.` Also, I am trying to parse an Item array, do I need to make a codec specifically for the array too?

Comment: I just found out that it has to do with me using `Item[]`, apparently it's not possible with MongoDB to use arrays, that sucks.

Comment: For those that follow, the default Lists/ArrayLists work fine; and if you really need an array it can be done!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do Mongo codecs for arrays using ArrayList as follows:

### com.example.model.Order

This is the class representing an Order. It includes an ArrayList of items.

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

/**
 * Class representing an Order.
 */
public class Order
{
    private ObjectId id;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    /**
     * Default constructor. Needed for testing.
     */
    public Order() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the id of the Order.
     * @param id The new id of the Order.
     */
    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the id of the Order.
     * @return The id of the Order.
     */
    public ObjectId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the items for the Order.
     * @param items The items for the Order.
     */
    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the items for the Order.
     * @return The items for the Order.
     */
    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item to the Order.
     * @param item The new Item to add to the Order.
     */
    public void addItem(Item item) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }
}
```

### com.example.model.Item

This is the class representing an Order Item. There can be any number of items that are a part of an order. Items are embedded within the Order document in Mongo.

```
package com.example.model;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

/**
 * Class representing an order item.
 */
public class Item
{
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Item() {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Sets the id of the Item.
     * @param id The new id of the Item.
     */
    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the id of the Item.
     * @return The id of the Item.
     */
    public ObjectId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name of the Item.
     * @param name The new name of the Item.
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name of the Item.
     * @return The name of the Item.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

### com.example.mongo.ItemConverter

Simple converter class that converts Items to/from Documents.

```
package com.example.mongo;

import com.example.model.Item;
import org.bson.Document;

/**
 * Converts Mongo Documents to/from Items.
 */
public class ItemConverter {
    /**
     * Convert the passed Item into a Mongo Document.
     * @param item The Item that you want to convert into a Mongo Document.
     * @return Returns the Document that was created from the passed Item.
     */
    public Document convert(Item item) {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.put("_id", item.getId());
        document.put("name", item.getName());

        return document;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the passed Mongo Document into an Item.
     * @param document The Document that you want to convert into an Item.
     * @return Returns the Item that was created from the passed Mongo Document.
     */
    public Item convert(Document document) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setId(document.getObjectId("_id"));
        item.setName(document.getString("name"));

        return item;
    }
}
```

### com.example.mongo.ItemCodec

Codec for encoding and decoding Items.

```
package com.example.mongo;

import com.example.model.Item;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.bson.BsonReader;
import org.bson.BsonString;
import org.bson.BsonValue;
import org.bson.BsonWriter;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.CollectibleCodec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

/**
 * Mongo Decoder for Items.
 */
public class ItemCodec implements CollectibleCodec<Item> {

    private final CodecRegistry registry;
    private final Codec<Document> documentCodec;
    private final ItemConverter converter;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public ItemCodec() {
        this.registry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        this.documentCodec = this.registry.get(Document.class);
        this.converter = new ItemConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Codec constructor.
     * @param codec The existing codec to use.
     */
    public ItemCodec(Codec<Document> codec) {
        this.documentCodec = codec;
        this.registry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        this.converter = new ItemConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Registry constructor.
     * @param registry The CodecRegistry to use.
     */
    public ItemCodec(CodecRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
        this.documentCodec = this.registry.get(Document.class);
        this.converter = new ItemConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Encode the passed Item into a Mongo/BSON document.
     * @param writer The writer to use for encoding.
     * @param item The Item to encode.
     * @param encoderContext The EncoderContext to use for encoding.
     */
    @Override
    public void encode(
                    BsonWriter writer,
                    Item item,
                    EncoderContext encoderContext
                ) {
        Document document = this.converter.convert(item);

        documentCodec.encode(writer, document, encoderContext);
    }

    /**
     * Get the class that this Codec works with.
     * @return Returns the class that this Codec works with.
     */
    @Override
    public Class<Item> getEncoderClass() {
        return Item.class;
    }

    /**
     * Decodes a Mongo/BSON document into an Item.
     * @param reader The reader containing the Document.
     * @param decoderContext The DecoderContext to use for decoding.
     * @return Returns the decoded Item.
     */
    @Override
    public Item decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
        Document document = documentCodec.decode(reader, decoderContext);
        Item item = this.converter.convert(document);

        return item;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a new ObjectId for the passed Item (if absent).
     * @param item The Item to work with.
     * @return Returns the passed Item with a new id added if there
     * was none.
     */
    @Override
    public Item generateIdIfAbsentFromDocument(Item item) {
        if (!documentHasId(item)) {
            item.setId(new ObjectId());
        }

        return item;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the passed Item has an id.
     * @param Item The Item that you want to check for
     * the presence of an id.
     * @return Returns whether or not the passed Item has an id.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean documentHasId(Item Item) {
        return (Item.getName() != null);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the id of the passed Item. If there is no id, it will
     * throw an IllegalStateException (RuntimeException).
     * @param Item The Item whose id you want to get.
     * @return Returns the id of the passed Item as a BsonValue.
     */
    @Override
    public BsonValue getDocumentId(Item Item)
    {
        if (!documentHasId(Item)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The document does not contain an _id");
        }

        return new BsonString(Item.getName());
    }

}
```

### com.example.mongo.OrderCodec

Codec for encoding/decoding Orders.

```
package com.example.mongo;

import com.example.model.Item;
import com.example.model.Order;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.bson.BsonReader;
import org.bson.BsonString;
import org.bson.BsonValue;
import org.bson.BsonWriter;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.CollectibleCodec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

/**
 * Mongo decoder for Orders.
 */
public class OrderCodec implements CollectibleCodec<Order> {

    private final CodecRegistry registry;
    private final Codec<Document> documentCodec;
    private final ItemConverter itemConverter;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public OrderCodec() {
        this.registry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        this.documentCodec = this.registry.get(Document.class);
        this.itemConverter = new ItemConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Codec constructor.
     * @param codec The existing codec to use.
     */
    public OrderCodec(Codec<Document> codec) {
        this.registry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        this.documentCodec = codec;
        this.itemConverter = new ItemConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Registry constructor.
     * @param registry The CodecRegistry to use.
     */
    public OrderCodec(CodecRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
        this.documentCodec = this.registry.get(Document.class);
        this.itemConverter = new ItemConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Encode the passed Order into a Mongo/BSON document.
     * @param writer The writer to use for encoding.
     * @param order The Order to encode.
     * @param encoderContext The EncoderContext to use for encoding.
     */
    @Override
    public void encode(
                    BsonWriter writer,
                    Order order,
                    EncoderContext encoderContext
                ) {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.put("_id", order.getId());
        document.put("items", order.getItems());

        documentCodec.encode(writer, document, encoderContext);
    }

    /**
     * Get the class that this Codec works with.
     * @return Returns the class that this Codec works with.
     */
    @Override
    public Class<Order> getEncoderClass() {
        return Order.class;
    }

    /**
     * Decodes a Mongo/BSON document into an Order.
     * @param reader The reader containing the Document.
     * @param decoderContext The DecoderContext to use for decoding.
     * @return Returns the decoded Order.
     */
    @Override
    public Order decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
        Document document = documentCodec.decode(reader, decoderContext);

        Order order = new Order();

        order.setId(document.getObjectId("_id"));

        ArrayList<Document> docArr = (ArrayList) document.get("items");
        for (Document doc : docArr) {
            Item item = this.itemConverter.convert(doc);
            order.addItem(item);
        }

        return order;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a new ObjectId for the passed Order (if absent).
     * @param order The Order to work with.
     * @return Returns the passed Order with a new id added if there
     * was none.
     */
    @Override
    public Order generateIdIfAbsentFromDocument(Order order) {
        if (!documentHasId(order)) {
            order.setId(new ObjectId());
        }

        return order;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the passed Order has an id.
     * @param order The Order that you want to check for
     * the presence of an id.
     * @return Returns whether or not the passed Order has an id.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean documentHasId(Order order) {
        return (order.getId() != null);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the id of the passed Order. If there is no id, it will
     * throw an IllegalStateException (RuntimeException).
     * @param order The Order whose id you want to get.
     * @return Returns the id of the passed Order as a BsonValue.
     */
    @Override
    public BsonValue getDocumentId(Order order) {
        if (!documentHasId(order)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The document does not contain an _id");
        }

        return new BsonString(order.getId().toHexString());
    }
}
```

### com.example.main.Main

Main class for the app. Here we register the codecs and create our MongoClient.

```
package com.example.main;

import com.example.model.Item;
import com.example.model.Order;
import com.example.mongo.ItemCodec;
import com.example.mongo.OrderCodec;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;

/**
 * Main class.
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * Main function for the app.
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        Codec<Document> documentCodec = codecRegistry.get(Document.class);
        Codec<Item> itemCodec = new ItemCodec(codecRegistry);
        Codec<Order> orderCodec = new OrderCodec(codecRegistry);
        codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                                            MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                                            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(
                                                documentCodec,
                                                itemCodec,
                                                orderCodec
                                            )
                                        );

        MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(codecRegistry).build();
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018), options);

        // Your code here.
    }
}
```

From there you can read/write orders and items to/from Mongo.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since I trust it and you put a lot of work into it, but I honestly haven't tried it and have no interest in trying since it's an old question, but thanks man!

Comment: This method contains far more manual conversion than simply writing the object as a Document manually. :(

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are overly complicated.  For the vast majority of the of the POJO classes you'll use, you do not need to write a codec at all.  Just register your object:

```
// Don't you hate it when sample code does not include references?
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;

...
{
    CodecRegistry myRegistry = fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(
                    PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                        .register(Item.class)
                        .build()
                    )
                ));
```

The above code makes a new registry by combining it with the default registry.  This is important because the default registry covers a ton of Java objects (lists, maps, etc.)

What if you have a lot of model objects?  No problem: register an entire package of objects...

```
{
    CodecRegistry myRegistry = fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(
                    PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                        .register("com.funkytown.model.package")
                        .build()
                    )
                ));
```

So next, how do you use this registry?  You have 3 options.

1. Attach it to a MongoClient instance:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(myRegistry).build());
```

2. Use it with a specific database:

```
myDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("FunkyTown").withCodecRegistry(myRegistry);
```

3. Use it with a specific collection:

```
myCollection = mongoClient.getDatabase("FunkyTown").getCollection("Items").withCodecRegistry(myRegistry);
```

The MongoDB Documentation isn't the greatest, but in my experience the POJO functionality is fast and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach will be to implement your own CodecProvider. This way you can manage all used codec implementation. Using your case:

Create MyCodecProvider

```
public class MyCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {

private final BsonTypeClassMap bsonTypeClassMap;

public MyCodecProvider(final BsonTypeClassMap bsonTypeClassMap) {
    this.bsonTypeClassMap = bsonTypeClassMap;
}

@Override
public <T> Codec<T> get(final Class<T> clazz, final CodecRegistry registry) {
    if (clazz == Document.class) {
        // construct DocumentCodec with a CodecRegistry and a BsonTypeClassMap
        return (Codec<T>) new org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec(registry, bsonTypeClassMap);
    }
    else if (clazz == Order.class) {
        return (Codec<T>) new OrderCodec(registry);
    }
    else if (clazz == Item.class) {
        return (Codec<T>) new ItemCodec(registry);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Now you may simple do this in your main class.

```
Map<BsonType, Class<?>> replacements = new HashMap<BsonType, Class<?>>();
    replacements.put(BsonType.DATE_TIME, Timestamp.class);
```

//        replacements.put(BsonType.DATE_TIME, Timestamp.class); in case you have complex java type

```
    BsonTypeClassMap bsonTypeClassMap = new BsonTypeClassMap(replacements);


    MyCodecProvider provider = new MyCodecProvider(bsonTypeClassMap);
    CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
            fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
    CodecRegistry codecRegistry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
    Codec<Document> documentCodec = codecRegistry.get(Document.class);

    codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
            CodecRegistries.fromProviders(provider),
            CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(pojoCodecRegistry),
            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(documentCodec));

    MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(codecRegistry).build();
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018), options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings() {
    MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .codecRegistry(createCustomCodecRegistry()).build();
    return mongoClientSettings;
}

@Bean
public CodecRegistry createCustomCodecRegistry() {
    return CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(
                    new UuidCodec(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD),
                    new ZonedDateTimeCodec()),
            MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just found out that it has to do with me using Item[], apparently
> it's not possible with MongoDB to use arrays, that sucks. –  vedi0boy
> Jan 12, 2017 at 17:01

This is great advice.  I was working with [MongoDB Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/quickstart-java) and trying to get it to work w/ the Azure Emulator and kept crapping out on 'codec issues'.  After a couple of days of googling/frustration I came upon this post while creating my codecs.

The Quick start has a couple of classes that define some variables as Arrays which, as you mentioned, can't be converted via the MongoDB Codec registery.

After I flipped those variables to Lists I was good to go.

Thanks for the advice :)