# MongoDB and java - CodecRegistry only returning an ID field rather than all fields in POJO?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, kotlin

I have the following code to create my mongo client in my Java Spring project:

```
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
        fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().register(Person.class).automatic(true).build()));

MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)
        .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString("myConnectionStrng"))
        .build();

MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("person").withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
MongoCollection<Person> collection = database.getCollection("personCollection", Person.class).withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);
```

My Kotilin Pojo is:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class Person {

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    var personID: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("name")
    var type: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("age")
    var age: Int? = null
    
}
```

I am able to get a response but the response is not as expected, i.e. it is

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "ID": "personId1"
    },
    {
      "ID": "personId2"
    },
    {
      "ID": "personId3"
    }
}
```

Each person object only shows some ID field rather than the fields in my POJO that I am expecting.

What am I missing here? Do I need to define a custom codec for my Pojo? I am unsure as first time using this mongo library.

Comment: try to return simple `BsonDocument`s (without deserialization with `Person.class`) and print what result you have. It will allow you to see what documents you actually receive and whether it has anything with serialization at all or it's something different

Comment: also, you should provide a filter you use

Comment: I am able to return the document correctly no problem. Can you provide an answer on how to use the coderegistry in my scenario?

Comment: my question was whether the bson document corresponds to what fields you have in your class? I'm not a java developer, but your case looks pretty straightforward if they match. Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70718741/9492730?

Comment: Also, not sure about `JsonProperty` in java, in c# this property is called `BsonProperty`. Will it work if you replace it?

Comment: see here https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/java/java-mapping-pojos/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is some working code where you can see that I write to the DB and read back data.

Several things are not clear in your question which may either explain why your attempt did not work, or I have misunderstood your requirement.

##### `Person` class

`Person` is a POJO - for this you probably don't want to use a straight `class`. In the way created it is awkward to construct the `Person` - I had to create a little helper method as there is no constructor in your class:

```java
private static Person makePerson(String id, String type, int age) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setPersonID(id);
    p.setType(type);
    p.setAge(age);
    return p;
}
```

Whereas, if you make a few small alterations and use a `data class` then this implicitly gives you a constructor, `toString()`, `hashCode()`:

```kotlin
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class Person (     //<< round brackets

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    var personID: String? = null,  //<< comma

    @JsonProperty("name")
    var type: String? = null,

    @JsonProperty("age")
    var age: Int? = null,

)
```

##### Codec setup

I don't think you have your Codecs setup in the right way.  (If a Codec is missing you will get a startup error.). Observe my working code.

##### What is your intended output?

You say it is "not as expected", is it that it is missing the age and name/type field? The field name is "ID" too, what do you want? `personID`, `_id` or `ID` ?

##### How is your output implemented now?

How are you extracting and displaying the data in JSON - you don't say but given the annotations you use (`@JsonProperty`), you must be using Jackson, I have included that in my code sample.  The Quick Start Guide you refer to talks about `@BsonProperty` - this is for a different purpose - for how to name the fields in the database, where as `@JsonProperty` is for naming in JSON.

##### Specimen code

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry);
        MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .build();
        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings)) {
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("person");
            MongoCollection<Person> collection = database.getCollection("personCollection", Person.class);

            List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
            persons.add(makePerson("personId1", "Lesley", 10));
            persons.add(makePerson("personId2", "Bob", 20));
            persons.add(makePerson("personId3", "Jane", 30));

            collection.insertMany(persons);

            List<Person> persons2 = collection.find().into(new ArrayList<Person>());
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(persons2));

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static Person makePerson(String id, String type, int age) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setPersonID(id);
        p.setType(type);
        p.setAge(age);
        return p;
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```json
[ {
  "_id" : "personId1",
  "name" : "Lesley",
  "age" : 10
}, {
  "_id" : "personId2",
  "name" : "Bob",
  "age" : 20
}, {
  "_id" : "personId3",
  "name" : "Jane",
  "age" : 30
} ]
```

And the dependencies I used:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
```